# Left Outer Join query results in an error

Tags: sql, outer-join, openbase

This query throws `ERROR - [position 0, near 'WHERE' in 'Select path.ePath, path._'] COMMA expected but not found in GROUP BY.`

This is my query:

```
Select path.ePath, path._rowid, doc.Filenumber, COUNT(doc.ePathUID) AS children
from docPath path LEFT OUTER JOIN
     docMeta doc
     ON doc.ePathUID = path._rowid
GROUP BY path._rowid
```

I'm expecting to count every child of the relationship, but the query isn't working.
How can I make the query work?

Comment: How is this Objective-C?

Comment: in all the RDBMS system (except MySQL), you can select only those columns without an aggregate function which are in `group by` list.

Comment: Your query has no `WHERE`, yet your error message does.  Are you sure this is the right query and the right error message?

Comment: Deepak's right.
path.ePath and doc.Filenumer must be in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I should have mentioned the RDBMS is OpenBase and I'm using their ObjC classes.

Comment: @nhgrif I removed the tag, now waiting for the edit to be accepted.

Comment: Replaced ON with WHERE and all is good.  Thanks to all for the nudge.

Comment: @JimGeldermann I answered your question, please review the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `ON` statement in the wrong context, it should be `WHERE` instead:

```
Select path.ePath, path._rowid, doc.Filenumber, COUNT(doc.ePathUID) AS children
from docPath path LEFT OUTER JOIN
     docMeta doc
     WHERE doc.ePathUID = path._rowid
GROUP BY path._rowid
```

Comment: @Allan While I agree with you (and updated my answer), I disagree with the upvote you just accumulated- your comment's no longer valid, please remove it.

Comment: As an addendum, Openbase's requirement that `where` be used instead of `on` is a deviation from the SQL standard. This syntax would be invalid in most RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by all columns that you have in your select except the ones where you are using aggregation functions. So it should be like :

```
Select path.ePath, path._rowid, doc.Filenumber, COUNT(doc.ePathUID) AS children
from docPath path LEFT OUTER JOIN
     docMeta doc
     ON doc.ePathUID = path._rowid
GROUP BY path.ePath, path._rowid, doc.Filenumber
```

For better understanding of why you have to group by all columns in the select list:
imagine that you have column ID with vaules 1,1 and Name with David,John . And you will type

```
select ID, Name from table group by ID
```

Now you wil group by ID = 1 , so you will get one row with value ID 1 and what value will be in column NAME ? SQL cant just random pick one of the names. So you have to group by both of them

```
select ID, Name from table group by ID,Name
```

And the result will be in this case:

```
ID NAME 
1   David 
1   John
```

Comment: Must be the classes I'm using, the ON throws the error.

Comment: This attempts to provide an answer to the question, but does not actually provide the correct solution.

Comment: Thats why its not accepted as an aswer as you can see... Dont see anything wrong with that. Thank you !